# My SQL のログイン中に

Tags: mysql

My SQL のログイン中に

（mysql -h IPアドレス -u root -p → パスワード）

フリーズするのはなぜですか ？

MAMP で ポート は 8888 ですが

My SQL で show variables like 'port'; → 3306 の 原因はありますか ？

Comment: 8888 は Aapche/Nginx に対して設定されているポートじゃないでしょうか？ https://qiita.com/shiki_neki/items/35d73f57615ed1f1d4fb

Comment: そうですね では PHPに設定するにはどうしたらいいですか ？

Comment: そもそもIPアドレスは正しいのですか？mampであればIPではなくてlocalhostでの接続が必要なはずです

Comment: 検索して使用しているIPアドレスで出てきたものをつかっているので間違いはありません My SQLの%（どの接続からもつなげられるワイルドカード(%)(今回の場合はIPアドレス)）でログインする場合はlocalhostで接続してはダメなようです

Comment: 自分にネットワーク内のIPを検索？MAMPですよね？だとすると外部のIPをいれてもつながらないはずです。MAMPは自分のPC仮想的にmysqlを導入するツールですのでlocalhostで繋ぐべきです

Comment: ワイルドカードがつながらない件はこちらを参考に https://b.l0g.jp/mysql/user-at-localhost/

Comment: ありがとうございます localhostでPHPからMy SQLにつなごうとすると権限を指定されます localhostに外部アクセス権は指定できないようなので ワイルドカード IPアドレスを指定してユーザーをつくりました ですがMAMP(port: 8888) mysql(3306) でつないでも 接続ができない のエラーになります

Comment: PHPとmysqlは同じmacPC(mampとして)で起動しているのですよね？でしたらlocalhostになります。

Comment: PHPとmysqlは同じmacPC(mampとして)で起動しているのですよね？ そうです ということは 他のなにか がちがうということでしょうか ？ Error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known のエラーが出ます 接続は http://localhost:8888/project/connect5.php です

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory